# Как получить доступ к this объекта внутри метода в котором есть вложенная функция?

Tags: javascript, this

у объекта есть метод:

```
move(){
        setInterval(function(){
        
            if(this.direction==0){  
          this.moveRight;         
          console.log("try move right");     
        }
        else
        if(this.direction==1){          
          this.moveLeft;           
          console.log("try move left");       
        }
        else
        if(this.direction==2){          
          this.moveUp;         
          console.log("try move up");         
        }
        else
        if(this.direction==3){          
          this.moveDown;           
          console.log("try move down");       
        }
        else{
            console.log("i am standing...");
        }
        return this;
        },1000);
}
```

как можно заставить выполняться методы  this.moveRight, this.moveLeft, this.moveUp, this.moveDown?

на данный момент контекст this - это Window, а методов - undefined.

Comment: добавить им скобочки что-бы их вызвать? `this.moveRight` -> `this.moveRight()`

Comment: ()=> используйте стрелочную функцию

Answer (score 2):

Пример функции-конструктора, которая создает объект, колбэк-функцию для `setInterval` оформлено стрелочной функцией для сохранения значения `this` (сам объект). Методы вызываются как и обычные функции с добавлением круглых скобок.

Объявил метод `moveRight` отдельно для демонстрации работы кода.

Справка:

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
[Методы объекта и this](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods)
[Стрелочные функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions)
[Привязка контекста](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind)

```js
function Mover () {
    this.direction = 0;
    
    this.moveRight = function() {
      console.log('moving right');
    }
    
    this.move = function(){
        setInterval( ()=> {
        
        if(this.direction==0){  
          this.moveRight();         
          console.log("try move right");     
        }
        else
        if(this.direction==1){          
          this.moveLeft();           
          console.log("try move left");       
        }
        else
        if(this.direction==2){          
          this.moveUp();         
          console.log("try move up");         
        }
        else
        if(this.direction==3){          
          this.moveDown();           
          console.log("try move down");       
        }
        else{
          console.log("i am standing...");
        }
        return this;
        },1000);
  }
}

let runner = new Mover();
runner.move();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Использовал стрелочные функции и все заработало. До этого пытался привязать контекст this при помощи bind(this), но это по-прежнему не возвращало ссылку на сам объект. Очень благодарен

Comment: @Ihor можете помещать `this` в переменную - `let t = this;`